# How can I use multiple inputs simultaneously?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

In input devices, I have to choose between Line-In or Microphone as an input device. But is there any way to use both at the same time?

[image]

I know that there was the ability to use more than one input in Windows. I am currently using *qJackCtl* to listen to my line-in.

My main goal is to use my Line-In with *qJackCtl* while I talk to someone on Discord using my microphone, is this possible?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you want to listen to for example music while you talk to somebody with a VOIP program? I think it works like that, when you run Ubuntu, which uses Pulse Audio. This software can mix input from more than one source.

Comment: @sudodus I know that you can make multiple output devices with Pulse Audio but i'm not sure you can make multiple input devices.

Comment: You want something different from what I thought. I have no experience of qJackCtl.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal use command:

```
arecord -l
```

To see information on recording device.

If only one subdevice shown, can only switch between sources, not play both.

You can mix and route multiple internal audio sources within JACK, but you will need an external mixer or 2nd sound device to have microphone and other external audio sources

Comment: typing arecord -l into a terminal lists "Subdevices: 1/1". So I guess it's not possible with the PulseAudio sound system?

Comment: yes, 1 subdevice = 1 input. get a USB device for 2nd input if needed